# Getting Nouns,Pronouns,Adjectives from a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.5, text-mining

Hi i am trying to get all the nouns,adjectives,verbs from the sentence using Textblob.I am getting the output in print command,but i am not able to save the data to csv file.

**Getting this following error:**

```
AttributeError: 'TextBlob' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

**Below is my code:**

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("path")
data=pd.read_csv("name.txt",header=None,names=["Text"])
res=list()

for Text in data["Text"]:
   blob = TextBlob(Text)
   print(blob.tags)

blob.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')
```

Comment: As the error states, there is no method function `.to_csv`. It appears to be a `pandas` method. I think the solution here is to apply the method to `blob.tags`. i.e `blob.tags.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')`. But this probably won't work as `to_csv` expects an object `dataframe`. You will probably need to create a `dataframe` and then use method `.to_csv` to export.

Comment: ok how can we create dataframe and use .to_csv?.Can you please explain me or edit in code.so that i can understand clearly

Comment: as you told blob.tags.to_csv is not working.I am getting the error 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: for Text in data["Text"]:
   blob = TextBlob(Text)
   df = pd.DataFrame(blob)
   print(df)
i have declared dataframe like this.but i am getting the following error.
DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Answer (score 2):

Assign blob.tags to a dataframe, then use df.to_csv(). Replace "blob.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')" with these two lines:

```
blob_tags_df = pd.DataFrame(blob.tags)
blob_tags_df.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')
```

Comment: do i need to give this to_csv in loop only?

Comment: No loop needed. Replace "blob.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')" with the two lines I wrote. Many pandas functions, including pd.DataFrame and df.to_csv(), handle the iteration for you. You don't need to code your own loops. That's one reason I like pandas. (Good question because I could have made that more clear.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using to_csv funtion in TextBlob object.You have to use it on pandas' Dataframe like this:

```
for Text in data["Text"]:
    blob = TextBlob(Text)
    t = blob.tags
    d = {}
    for c in t:
        if c[1] not in d:
            d[c[1]] = [c[0]]
        else:
            d[c[1]].append(c[0])

    for i in d:
        while len(d[i]) != len(d):
            d[i].append('-')

    filtered_data = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print(filtered_data)
    filtered_data.to_csv("abhi_blob.csv",sep=',')
```

Comment: @ABHISHEKL glad to help :)